# How to list down all the AMI image IDs for Red Hat in AWS using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, redhat, amazon-ami

I'm working on a task where I need to validate if a user has created an `EC2 instance` with `RHEL latest image` using `Cloudtrail` logs for that user.

I was able to find the `AMI image IDs` used by that user using `boto3`.

I want to check whether the `AMI image ID` used by the user is present in the list of image IDs provided by `RHEL`.

How do I list down all the `AMI image IDs` for `RedHat Inc`.

I have gone through the `boto3` documentation [describe_images()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images)

There's a param `Owners` in it. But not sure what should I pass in there to get all the image IDs for Redhat.

**PS:** Found that `Redhat owner ID` is - **309956199498** and we can query with it using `ec2.describe_images()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code lists all RHEL-8 AMI IDs in the specified region:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
filters = [
    {'Name': 'owner-id', 'Values': ['309956199498']}, 
    {'Name':'name', 'Values':['RHEL-8*']}
]
images = ec2.images.filter(Filters=filters).all()

for image in images:
    print(image.id)
```

Adapted from the CLI command in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/15356.